# How can I find out which cards are supported by the nouveau driver?

Tags: nouveau

I'm looking at different Nvidia cards and would like to know which are supported by the nouveau driver - is there a list of these available and the levels of support offered?

Comment: Supported in what way? By default Ubuntu uses the open-source driver, so basically it supports all the basic function of Nvidia cards.

Comment: @Toki I've updated my question to define the scope better.

Comment: I think the first answer pretty much sums it up.

Comment: @Toki you didn't place an answer yet

Comment: I will be honest, I had no answer other than the first comment. Your question was simply too vague. I'm relatively new to the open-source scene myself, I had no extra details (related to your question) to give you, so I simply commented to help you get the answer you were seeking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a list of Nvidia chipsets and supported features by the nouveau driver: http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/FeatureMatrix

[image: FeatureMatrix]

You can see the specific devices by clicking on the chipset name.

Comment: Looks like my card is actually pretty well supported.

Comment: Good for you.I installed Nvidia driver because of CUDA.I don't know if nouveau is better.Maybe I should test it!