# how to setup nouveau driver at boot time in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: boot, startup, nouveau

I would like add nouveau driver during boot time but I don't know where is the place in ubuntu 12.04 to add modprobe nouveau.

Comment: I think this is a semi-duplicate (or at least answered by this): http://askubuntu.com/questions/12937/remove-nvidia-driver-and-go-back-to-nouveau?rq=1 -- it should be picked up if you don't have the restricted nvidia driver installed and if your graphics card is supported by nouveau: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26873/how-can-i-find-out-which-cards-are-supported-by-the-nouveau-driver?rq=1

Comment: you don't understand me... I already switched to nouveau in X session. But I'm asking what I should do to setup this permamently during boot not per one session.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you don't see lines "*blacklist nouveau*" with this command:

   ```
   grep -ri nouveau /etc/modprobe*
   ```
2. To permanently add nouveau at boot time:

   ```
   echo "nouveau" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau.conf
   ```